# How to set hash key expiration in redis according to the existance of the key

Tags: python, redis

I would like to set the expiration of some hash keys, and if it is the first time to hset the key, I wish to set an expiration, other wise, I prefer to keep the expiration that is set at the first time.

Since there are huge of hash keys, I prefer to do it in pipeline, however the function below not works well.

The line `pipe.exists(hkey)` return an obj of pipe, which is always True, so the if clause always go to one part regardless of the existence of the hash key.

And my question is: is there a method to set the expiration of a hash key according to the existence of the hash key with pipeline?

```
def test1(hkey, v):
    with r.pipeline() as pipe:
        # tmp = pipe.exists(hkey)
        # pipe.exists(hkey) is a pipe obj, which is always True, 
        # this line not work as expected and the two lines below it will never be excuted.
        if not pipe.exists(hkey):
            pipe.hset(hkey, v, v)
            pipe.expire(hkey, 3600)
        else:
            # no matter whether the hash key is exist or not, the if else statment always goes to this line.
            pipe.hset(hkey, v, v)
        pipe.execute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CANNOT achieve that with pipeline, since you never know whether the key is existed until the whole pipeline has been executed. Instead, you can use [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to do the job:

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local field = ARGV[1]
local value = ARGV[2]
local ttl = ARGV[3]

local exist = redis.call('exists', key)

redis.call('hset', key, field, value)

if exist == 0 then
    redis.call('expire', key, ttl)
end
```

Check [this](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#lua-scripting) to see how to run Lua script with redis-py. Then run the script with pipeline to reduce the `RTT`.

**UPDATE**

If you insist on using `WATCH` to do the job, you can try the following code:

```
with r.pipeline() as pipe:
    while 1:
        try:
            pipe.watch(hkey)

            exist = pipe.exists(hkey)

            pipe.multi()

            if not exist:
                pipe.hset(hkey, v, v)
                pipe.expire(hkey, 3600)
            else:
                pipe.hset(hkey, v, v)

            pipe.execute()
            break;
        except WatchError:
            continue
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help, but I still have 2 questions and could you share more advices?
1. Does Lua works well when in concurrency? I get some info that when Lua s
cript is using, nothing else can run concurrently, is it right?
2. How about using watch()? I mean, pipe.watch(hkey); pipe.exists(hkey); pipe.unwatch(); then, the other parts. I tested it on my laptop, it works, but the bad news is when WATCH is used, every pipe.exists() cost time to connect and get the result from redis server. So, my question is: is there any risk to use WATCH in this way, not in a transaction?

Comment: 1. Lua script works the same as other commands. Redis runs them atomically. 2. AFAIK, your `WATCH` solution cannot work. It has the same problem as pipeline: you never know the exist result before the pipeline or transaction finishes.

Comment: Hi, for_stack, thank you very much for your reply, and just one more question, I find an example from [here](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#pipelines), and there is a method to get result during a pipeline with WATCH, it seems it is possible to get values during a pipeline, because WATCH put a pipeline into immediate execution mode?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. You can use `WATCH` to do the job. Please see the update of my answer.

Comment: Could I remove MULTI if the transaction is not required? I replaced MULTI with UNWATCH in test, it seems it works, are there any risks?

Comment: NO. `WATCH` works with `MULTI`. Otherwise, you'll get race condition. Say, you watch a key, and test its existence. If the key already exists, you try to `HSET` the hash without setting the expiration. However, before you do that, the key has been deleted by other client or just expired. Then you'll set the key without any expiration, and the key exists forever.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.