# Is there any way to insert some python statement when using python redis transaction?

Tags: python, redis

Redis is very easy to use in python. However, now I have a problem in using Redis transaction. First, I have to get a `key` in Redis, next I have to check whether the value bound to this key is legal. I hope those operations to be atomic. Here is my code.

```
pipe = redis_conn.pipeline()
pipe.multi()
var = pipe.get('key_want_to_be_read')
if is_legal(val):
    do_something
else:
    do_another_thing
pipe.execute()
```

However, when I run these code, python name `var` is not bound to a value stored in redis, but a `Pipeline<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>`, So. Is there any way to get a key and bound it to a python name in redis transaction?

Comment: You should use `WATCH` command or  Lua script to do the job. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060226/how-to-set-hash-key-expiration-in-redis-according-to-the-existance-of-the-key) for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a lua script like this:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
redis_script = r.register_script("""
    local valueToTest = redis.call('GET','{key}')
    --Test key in lua
    """.format(key=key_to_be_read))
```

And then call it with `redis_script()`

From the [Redis site](https://redis.io/commands/eval) this is atomic:

> Redis uses the same Lua interpreter to run all the commands. Also
>   Redis guarantees that a script is executed in an atomic way: no other
>   script or Redis command will be executed while a script is being
>   executed.